# Select Album Using Template Match

Tags: php, xslt

I have created a drop down selection box for selecting an album to view. When the user makes a selection, they then click View Album and the id of the selection they made is sent via POST to the viewing page: select_album.php

The list of all albums is queried from the database and displayed in the drop down selection. Each album has an id associated with it. Based on which album is selected, when the user clicks on View Album, they are sent to select_album.php where the information for that album is displayed.

The default selection in the drop down is [SELECT ALBUM] and is just used as a place holder. My problem is that when [SELECT ALBUM] is chosen and View Album is clicked, the user is sent to select_album.php and sees a blank page. I need the page to display album information: NO ARTIST: NO ALBUM TITLE
Label: NO LABEL, 0 TRACKS, etc. I will display an album image that shows no album art.

I think what I need to do is somehow make a template match, but am confused where to start.

[This is the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDYnf.jpg)
[This is example of a regular album page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY495.jpg)

select_album.php

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from albums ORDER BY artist";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row

?>  
<form method='POST' action='write_xml.php'><b>SELECT AN ALBUM TO VIEW:</b><br />
<select name='id' size=1>
<option value=''>[SELECT ALBUM]</option>
<?php
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>  
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['artist']. ' - '   .$row['name']; ?></option>
<?php
        }
        } else {
        echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
?>
</select><br /><br />

<input type='submit' name='process' value='VIEW ALBUM' />
```

music_inventory.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:param name="albumid">JA1</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="music_inventory">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="album[@id=$albumid]"/>
</xsl:template>
<!--creates hyperlink-->
<xsl:template match="album">
 <img src="{@albumart}" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width: 200px;" />

    <div style="position: absolute; left: 215px; font-size: 16pt; color: #993333;">

        <b><xsl:value-of select="artist"/>: <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="{@id}.xhtml">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </a></b>

    </div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left: 215px; top: 40px; font-size: 10pt;">
   <b>Label: </b><xsl:value-of select="label"/><br />
   <b>Year: </b><xsl:value-of select="year"/><br />
   <b>Disc <xsl:value-of select="disc"/> of <xsl:value-of select="totaldiscs"/></b><br />
 </div>

 <div style="position: absolute; left: 215px; top: 100px; font-size: 12pt;">
   <b>Track Listing:</b><br/>
   <xsl:for-each select="tracklist/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>: <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
   </xsl:for-each>
 </div>

</xsl:template>
```

write_xml.php

```
$query="select * from albums";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);

$fp=fopen('music_inventory.xml','w');
$header="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE album SYSTEM   \"music_inventory.dtd\">\n";
$header.="<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/css\" href=\"music_inventory.css\"?>\n";
$header.="<music_inventory>\n";
$written=fwrite($fp,$header);

$xml_data="";


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
    // Insert code here to write the outer album info
    $type=null;
$xml_data .= "<album id=\"".$row['id']."\" type=\"".$type."\"   albumart=\""   .$row['albumart']."\">";
$xml_data .= "<artist>".htmlentities($row['artist'])."</artist>\n";
$xml_data .= "<name>".$row['name']."</name>\n";
$xml_data .= "<year>".$row['year']."</year>\n";
$xml_data .= "<label>".$row['label']."</label>\n";
$xml_data .= "<disc>".$row['disc']."</disc>\n";
$xml_data .= "<totaldiscs>".$row['totaldiscs']."</totaldiscs>\n";



    switch($row["type"])
    {
            case 'E':
                    $type='EP';
                    break;
            case 'F':
                    $type='full_length';
                    break;
            case 'S':
                    $type='soundtrack';
                    break;
            case 'C':
                    $type='compilation';
                    break;
            case 'M':
                    $type='multi_disc';
                    break;
            default:
                    $type='unknown';
                    break;
    }


            $xml_data .= "<tracklist>\n";      


    $track_query="select track_number,track_title,track_artist from tracklist where id='" . $row["id"] . "' order by track_number";
    $track_result=mysqli_query($db,$track_query);
    while($track_row=mysqli_fetch_array($track_result))
    {
            // Insert code here to write the inner track list info
            $xml_data .= "<track id=\"".$track_row['track_number']."\">".htmlentities($track_row['track_title'])."</track>\n";

    }


    $xml_data .= "</tracklist>\n";
    $xml_data .= "</album>\n";

}





$written=fwrite($fp,$xml_data);
$footer="</music_inventory>\n";
$written=fwrite($fp,$footer);
fclose($fp);

$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("music_inventory.xsl");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("music_inventory.xml");

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);

$proc->setParameter('', 'albumid', $_POST["id"]);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XSLT, you are currently selecting the template for the album like so:

```
<xsl:template match="music_inventory">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="album[@id=$albumid]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to handle the case where `$albumid` is empty, you can add an `xsl:if` condition after this.

```
<xsl:template match="music_inventory">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="album[@id=$albumid]"/>
   <xsl:if test="$albumid = ''">
       <p>NO ALBUM</p>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Or maybe like this, to handle a case where the `$albumid` is set, but doesn't exist:

```
<xsl:template match="music_inventory">
   <xsl:variable name="$album" select="album[@id=$albumid]" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$album"/>
   <xsl:if test="$album">
       <p>NO ALBUM</p>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, another solution would be to simply disable the "View Album" button whenever "SELECT ALBUM" is selected, to avoid an unnecessary postback.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Only one minor typo: You have <xsl: if - for the opening tag and then </xls - for the closing tag. Your closing tag just needs to be </xsl.